# Simple Linux SMTP Server

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp, exim, ssmtp

I need to provide 3 SMTP servers for clients to use for printers and scanners that require an SMTP server to send email out, they will be load balanced with DNS round robin. All I need it to do is send out email as an open relay (it will be behind a firewall). I have yet to find documentation on how to do this easily.

Comment: Why do you need three servers for this? Have you started to read *any* documentation?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault!  Generally, we expect questions to show that you have done at least some research, and are encountering a specific problem or quandary.  Though this question will likely be closed, please feel free to open a new one if you have a specific stumbling block.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu postfix is about as easy and simple as it gets:

https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/postfix.html

#### Installation

To install Postfix run the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Simply press return when the installation process asks questions, the configuration will be done in greater detail in the next stage.

#### Basic Configuration

To configure postfix, run the following command:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

The user interface will be displayed. On each screen, select the following values:

```
Internet Site
mail.example.com
steve
mail.example.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
No
127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/24
0
+
all
```

Replace `mail.example.com` with the domain for which you'll accept email, `192.168.0.0/24` with the actual network and class range of your mail server, and steve with the appropriate username.

Now is a good time to decide which mailbox format you want to use. By default Postfix will use mbox for the mailbox format. Rather than editing the configuration file directly, you can use the postconf command to configure all postfix parameters. The configuration parameters will be stored in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file. Later if you wish to re-configure a particular parameter, you can either run the command or change it manually in the file.

To configure the mailbox format for Maildir:

```
sudo postconf -e 'home_mailbox = Maildir/'
```

This will place new mail in `/home/username/Maildir` so you will need to configure your Mail Delivery Agent (MDA) to use the same path.

Comment: sure thing, ubuntu documentation links are very stable tho.

Comment: thx for code blocking too

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Much better! I know it seems like a little thing but if the content of that site goes away or changes then your answer becomes less relevant. The idea with the SE sites is that the Q's and A's should coexist together and should remain meaningful. Gave you a +1 for the effort. Keep up the good work!